# How to copy data from one AWS S3 folder to another folder in the same bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image]

Trying to copy data from one folder in the S3 bucket to another folder in the same bucket.  Is it possible from GUI or AWS CLI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy the contents of one prefix (folder) to another prefix (folder) by using this command -

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://<bucket-name>/<source-folder-name> s3://<bucket-name>/<target-folder-name> --region <region-name>
```

Comment: History/versions is missing in the copied contents. How to copy with version?